# Select where count of other query of same table

Tags: sql, select, count

I have got table "Members" with fields ID,UserID,GroupID
And I would like to select only GroupIDs where count of Members is more than 1 for each members, like this:

```
ID  UserID  GroupID
1   1       1        /* we are selecting groups for guy with ID 1, here are 3 people */
2   2       1
3   3       1
4   1       2        /* here the guy is alone in group, ignore him! */
5   1       3        /* select this one too for guy 1, because #members>1 */
6   2       3
```

Performing group select for guy with ID 1 including that there must be atleast 2 people in same group, so this would return: 1, 3

But I have no idea how to do this in SQL, I would like to do something like this, but, it obviously doesn't work:

```
SELECT GroupID
 FROM Members 
 WHERE UserID=1
  AND COUNT(
   SELECT UserID FROM Members WHERE GroupID=**currently iterated group**
  )>1;
```

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want groups with at least two members, one of which has `userid = 1`.  The following query finds these groups using `group by` and `having`:

```
select m.groupId
from Members m
group by m.groupId
having count(*) > 1 and
       sum(case when m.userid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the groups with more than one member that user 1 is a member of:

```
select groupid 
from members 
where groupid in (select groupid from members where userid = 1) 
group by groupid having count(*) > 1;
```

The solution offered by @GordonLinoff is probably better (more efficient) though.